# SQL query same table twice but get one output column only mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to list the two ENTITY_ID's (by querying the RELATIONS table with WHERE between two dates) related to each SOURCE/ACCOUNT pairs in the RELATIONS table.

```
- ENTITIES table
ENTITY_ID (PK)
ENTITY_NAME

    - ACCOUNTS table
    SOURCE    (PK)
    ACCOUNT   (PK)
    ENTITY_ID (FK)

        - RELATIONS table
        RELATION_ID (PK)
        SOURCE_1    (FK)
        ACCOUNT_1   (FK)
        SOURCE_2    (FK)
        ACCOUNT_2   (FK)
        TIMESTAMP
```

The query below retrieves the ENTITY_ID of one SOURCE/ACCOUNT pair (SOURCE_1/ACCOUNT_1), but I'd also need the ENTITY_ID of SOURCE_2/ACCOUNT_2, not as second column in the output, but as a second row (value).

```
SELECT A.ENTITY_ID
  FROM RELATIONS R
  JOIN ACCOUNTS A
    ON R.SOURCE_1  = A.SOURCE
   AND R.ACCOUNT_1 = A.ACCOUNT
 WHERE R.TIMESTAMP >= DATETIME1 AND R.TIMESTAMP < DATETIME2
```

Example of output needed (1 column, 2 values):

```
                    ENTITY_ID
Output record #1    1234
Output record #2    1235
```

Comment: I'd fix the presentation in an above layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the values in different rows, then you can do:

```
SELECT A.ENTITY_ID
FROM RELATIONS R JOIN
     ACCOUNTS A
     ON (R.SOURCE_1  = A.SOURCE AND
         R.ACCOUNT_1 = A.ACCOUNT 
        ) OR
        (R.SOURCE_2  = A.SOURCE AND
         R.ACCOUNT_2 = A.ACCOUNT
        )
WHERE R.TIMESTAMP >= DATETIME1 AND
      R.TIMESTAMP < DATETIME2;
```

`OR`s generally kill the performance of `JOIN`s, but this will work if your data is not very big.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, my RELATIONS table has 60M rows, might be a bit too much for the OR. We'll see. I'll compare if it's better to run the query twice and UNION later instead. Thanks again

Comment: @user3489502 . . . `UNION`/`UNION ALL` is probably a better approach with that many rows.